# What are some middle game chess books that are good for beginners?

Tags: learning, books, beginner, middlegame, recommendations

What are some great middlegame chess books that are for beginners that will help me to improve my middle game in chess? There aren't a lot of books on the middle game.

Comment: By the way, there's hardly any middle-game books targeted at beginners since if youre studying the middle-game you probably arent a beginner by definition.

Answer (score 1):

As alluded to in [this answer](https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/40074/26335), Seirawan has two useful books that are wonderful for beginners.

- [***Play Winning Chess***](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1857443314) covers the fundamentals very well, focusing on concepts such as Force (material), Time (tempo), Space, and Pawn Structure. Targeted at the beginner level.
- [***Winning Chess Strategies***](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004Y6AI30) is the perfect introduction to positional ideas for beginners. Very useful for beginners struggling to find ideas to generate candidate moves. Includes positional puzzles.

[image: Image with book covers]

Answer (score 0):

Beginners don't really need to understand the middle game. You mostly just need an understanding of basics and tactics to move beyond the beginner stage. Seirawan had a series  with a couple of books on the middle game. That's probably plenty for beginners.

Once you start pushing for 2000, Nimzo's *My System* and Silman's HTRYC are good.

If I were teaching middle-game planning to a beginner, I would just say, pick a target and point all of your pieces at it. The target can be the king or a weak pawn or a hanging piece or whatever. If you don't know what to do, just improve the mobility of your pieces. Most middle-game planning comes down to increasing mobility anyway.